# How to print the video meta output by the browser version of ffmpeg.wasm to the console of Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ffmpeg, frontend, webassembly

I would like to ask about how to use the browser version of ffmpeg.wasm.

Through my investigation, I know that the following command can be used to output the video metadata to a file in the terminal of windows or mac.

```
ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 -f ffmetadata testoutput.txt
```

and then I can get this matadata like this:
[image]

I want to parse the metadata of the video through the browser, and then print the metadata to the Google console (or output to a file). At present, I know that the browser version of ffmpeg.wasm can achieve this function, but I have looked at its examples, which does not involve this part of the content. (https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/blob/master/examples/browser/image2video.html)

But I want to print it to the console of Google Chrome through the browser version(usage:brower) of ffmpeg.wasm (https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm).
So I want to ask you how to achieve this, thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you can show the code, thank you.